# Codeception in laravel does not show Exceptions during functional tests

Tags: php, laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to do BDD style project. So far I have everything set up. Problem is, if I have something like this:

```
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('email', 'test@example.com');
$I->fillField('passord', 'secret');
$I->submitForm();
$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());
```

I have no route so far so I expect that `codecept run` will show me the exception. But it shows me only this:

```
1) Failed to test valid login in DemanderAuthorizationCest::testValidLogin (tests/functional/DemanderAuthorizationCest.php)

 Step  I fill field "email","test@example.com"
 Fail  Form field by Label or CSS 'email' was not found.
```

I believe this is because of Laravel's error handling, but I don't know how to fix it.

My functional.suite.yml looks like this:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - \Helper\Functional
    - Asserts
    - Laravel5:
        environment_file: .env.testing
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are running an acceptance test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    // ...
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if (App::environment() == 'testing') {
            throw $e;
        }
        return parent::report($e);
    }
    // ...
}
```